# Master Data Sheet from a folder without Blank spaces between pulled files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know there has been a lot said on the topic of a Master Sheet already. However as I haven't found the relevant answer to my question, I was hoping you could be so kind and help. The issue is very trivial I have a script that looks into the specific folder and grabs the data from those sheets. I just don't know how to modify it so that it doesn't retrieve the empty cells too ( due to the import range function sitting in the subfiles). So in the nutshell, it would be great if the code will only retrieve a range of data, for column "A"  <> ""

```
function myFunction() {

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xcv");

var filesInterator = folder.getFiles();


var file;
var fileType;
var ssID;
var combinedData = [];
var data;


while(filesInterator.hasNext()){
file = filesInterator.next();
fileType = file.getMimeType();
if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
  ssID = file.getId();
  data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
  combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);

} // if ends here
}  // while loops ends here

Logger.log(combinedData.length);

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master");
ws.getRange("A2:BK").clearContent();
ws.getRange(2,1,combinedData.length,combinedData[0].length).setValues(combinedData);

}

function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("ABC");
var data = ws.getRange("A2:KB" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
return data;

}
```

Comment: It depends on the shape of the range and what output you want. Can you provide an example range and the desired output? What do you need to do with the output? Do you need to paste it into another range or does that not matter?

Comment: @ iansedano , so basically what I trying to figure out is I believe an IF statement in app script that say something along these lines filter(IMPORTRANGE("xxx";"ABC!A2:kb");IMPORTRANGE("xxx";"ABC!A2:a")<>""). The above code works just fine with grabbing sheets from the given folder and combining the data into a Master Sheet, I'm just struggling to tell the code to omit empty rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("ABC");
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:KB" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[0] != ''});
  return data;
}
```

[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: thanks for your help, Sir! This is exactly what I was looking for. Have a great rest of the weekend!